# Append an HTML block after another appended block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax script that retrieves more X results from the database. The number of results depend on the `offset` hidden field value. The script doubles it. After these X new data, it should append after it another block of an image, but I noticed that if I print in the console the selected element, it shows this:

> [prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(4)"]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: m.fn.init[1]selector: "#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(4)"**proto**: Object[0]
>
> [prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(6)"]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: m.fn.init[1]selector: "#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(4)"**proto**: Object[0]

Which means it's trying to append to something that still doesn't exist. Below is the Ajax script:

```
function appendAd(offset, no) {
    console.log($('#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(' + offset + ')'));

    $('#revendas_conteudo .load_more .item_estoque:nth-child(' + offset + ')').after(
        '<div style="float: left; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" class="anuncio">' + 
            '<img src="/uploads/publicidades/publicidade_busca_' + no + '.jpg">' +
        '</div>'
    ); 
}

$('#revendas_conteudo .btn_carregar_mais').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/auto/carros/load_more',
        data: {
            'offset': $('#offset').val(),
            'limit': $('#limit').val(),
            'no': $('#no').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            i = 0;
            max = obj.total === obj.offset;
            var newOffset;
            no = parseInt($('#no').val()) + 1;

            $('#limit').val(obj.limit);
            $('#offset').val(obj.offset);
            $('#no').val(obj.no);

            $.each(obj.res, function (k, v) {
                newOffset = parseInt($('#offset').val()) + 1; 
               
                $('#revendas_conteudo .load_more').append(
                    '<div class="item_estoque">' +
                        '<div class="avatar">' +
                            '<img src="/uploads/carros/destaque/' + obj.res[i].imagem_destaque + '"/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="texto_anuncio">' +
                            '<h4>' + obj.res[i].modelo.substring(0, 19) + '</h4>' +
                            '<div class="detalhes">' +
                                '<span>' + obj.res[i].marca + ' | ' + obj.res[i].combustivel + ' | ' + obj.res[i].cor + '</span>' +
                                '<span>' + obj.res[i].ano + '</span>' +
                                '<span>' + obj.res[i].kilometragem + ' km</span>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<span class="anunciante">' + obj.res[i].nome_anunciante + '</span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="texto_anuncio_right">' +
                            '<span class="preco"> R$ ' + obj.res[i].preco + '</span>' +
                            '<a href="/comprar/detalhes/' + obj.res[i].id + '" class="bt_vejamais">Veja Mais</a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );

                i++;
                $('#offset').val(newOffset);
                $('#no').val(no);

                if (newOffset == obj.total) {
                    $('#revendas_conteudo .btn_carregar_mais').css({backgroundColor: '#999'}).html('Sem mais resultados').attr('disabled', true);
                } 
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            appendAd($('#offset').val(), no);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I do it? To append a block after another HTML block has been appended?

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous question: [Load more data from database with Codeigniter and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35413448/load-more-data-from-database-with-codeigniter-and-ajax).

Comment: Not exactly. What I need now is how to append the HTML block to another appended block.